# After some calls getting k8s.Autorest.HttpOperationException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Unauthorized'

Tags: c#, .net, kubernetes, amazon-eks, client-library

We are trying to monitor an argo workflow using the Kubernetes client for C#. The Kubernetes server is hosted on AWS EKS cluster. The method we are using is `IKubernetes.CustomObjects.GetNamespacedCustomObjectAsync()`. The issue is that the first 15 minutes or so all calls go through just fine. After that we start getting the above stated exception.

The kubeconfig file was created using the `aws eks update-kubeconfig` so I'm assuming no errors are present there (also the calls going through initially).

Sample of code used:

```
public static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task MonitorWorkflowAsync(this IKubernetes kubernetes, string? workflowName)
    {
        string? state = null;
        do
        {
            try
            {
                dynamic response = await kubernetes.CustomObjects.GetNamespacedCustomObjectAsync(KubeConstants.Group, KubeConstants.Version, KubeConstants.NamespaceParameter, KubeConstants.Plural, workflowName);
                state = response?.GetProperty("status")?.GetProperty("phase").ToString();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error(ex.Message + "/n" + ex.StackTrace);

            }
            
            Log.Information("Pipeline: {0}\t Status: {1} ", workflowName,
           state);
            if (state?.Equals(KubeConstants.Running,
                StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) ?? false)
                Thread.Sleep(30000);

            if (!(state?.Equals(KubeConstants.Failure,
                    StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) ?? true)) continue;
            Log.Warning(
                "The workflow {0} has failed to execute properly. Please access the Kubernetes cluster and troubleshoot OR check your yaml file used to create the workflow!",
                workflowName);
            break;
        }
        while (state?.Equals(KubeConstants.Running, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) ?? false);
       
    }
}
```

Kubernetes Client version : 8.0.6

Kubernetes Version: 1.22

.NET version: 6.0

Comment: The server may have limitations to number of connections from same user. or following : More specifically, Kubernetes is designed to accommodate configurations that meet all of the following criteria:
No more than 110 pods per node.
No more than 5000 nodes.
No more than 150000 total pods.
No more than 300000 total containers.

Comment: @jdweng That's true although I'm currently operating below those limits. I believe it is the token that expires but the Kubernetes client for C# documentation says it refreshes the token automatically.

Comment: But the code is working for 15 minutes!!!